# Creating Android Chevron Buttons which overlap

Tags: android

I've seen quite a few apps that separate their navigation or breadcrumb buttons with chevrons like below:

```
         \           \ 
Button A  \ Button B  \
          /           /
         /           /
```

OnClick each button will change its background colour. For example Button B will change the colour between both chevrons. However because buttons are normally rectangular this will change part of Button A's background. Similarly when Button A is pressed this will change part of button B's background. I've tried to do this by using overlapping buttons and also by using images between the buttons that will swap out various PNG's (used as a mask). Not a lot of success though unfortunately. Does anyone know if there is a standard way of doing this?